# Comparing Strings in Pandas dataframe in elif fashion

Tags: python, string, pandas, lambda

I am trying to compare strings in a dataframe with the specific caveat that if one of the strings already equals "Missing" that value will be carried over.

For instance if my df looks like

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['Dog','Cat','Missing'],
      'Col2':['Dog', 'Monkey', 'Rat']})
```

and I asked if Col1 is in Col2 the results would be

```
True, False, Missing
```

The following code allows the comparison of values per row (providing me with "true" and "false" values), but I have been struggling with how to incorporate the check for "Missing"

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[Col1] in row[Col2], axis=1)
```

Perhaps I should abandon the notion of using a lambda function in this case and switch over to a if/elif/ statement such as in this pseudocode:

```
if df[df[Col1]] == "Missing":
     df['result'] = 'Missing'
elif df[df[Col1]] in df[df[Col2]]:
    df['result'] = 'True'
else:
    df['result'] = 'False'
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask1 = df['Col1'] == 'Missing'
mask2 = df.apply(lambda row: row['Col1'] in row['Col2'], axis=1)

df['result'] = np.where(mask1, 'Missing',
               np.where(mask2, 'True', 'False'))

print (df)
      Col1    Col2   result
0      Dog     Dog     True
1      Cat  Monkey    False
2  Missing     Rat  Missing
```